# Sign in test using Rspec+Capybara+Selenium

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, capybara, integration-testing

I am trying to pass the login test using rspec integration testing, i have set up rspec and it is working too but it is not passing the test. The code is given below

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Users" do
 describe "GET /users/sign_in" do
    it "works! (now write some real specs)", :js => true do
    visit user_session_path
    fill_in "Email", :with => "a@example.org"
    fill_in "Password", :with => "abc123"
    click_button "Sign in"
    page.should have_content('Signed in successfully.')
  end
 end
end
```

Now, when i try to log it is failing. I have also run the command

```
rake db:test:prepare
```

Am i missing anything?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Add some more information like the exact failure message..

Comment: it is not failing... it fires up a mozilla window visit sign up page and fill n the credentials and it is unable to login with those credentials and it not finding the text 'Signed in successfully.' and gives me "Failure/Error: page.should have_content('Signed in successfully.')
       expected to find text "Signed in successfully." in "KOOPERATIONSPLANER Registration Sign in × You need to sign in or sign up before continuing. Sign in Email Password Remember me Sign up Forgot your password? Didn't receive confirmation instructions? Didn't receive unlock instructions?"
"

Comment: and when i logs in with these credentials it logins successfully. I dont know whats wrong with this? Is there a problem with test database?

Answer (score 0):

First of all create a user in before block!

But I had the problem even when user had been created. The problem was that created user was not seen by Devise. To solve it add these lines to spec_helper

```
# enable shared connection
class ActiveRecord::Base
  mattr_accessor :shared_connection
  @@shared_connection = nil

  def self.connection
    @@shared_connection || retrieve_connection
  end
end

# Forces all threads to share the same connection. This works on
# Capybara because it starts the web server in a thread.
ActiveRecord::Base.shared_connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
```

Comment: 1. Did you have a user in DB before running the test? (According to posted code - you didn't). Recheck it. 2. Do you use gem `devise` or other gem or own system to authontificate?

Comment: 1. In my development DB i have user but not in my Test DB. 2. Yes i am using devise.

Comment: Thanks @gotva.... I have seed the data in the Test DB and now it working perfectly ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue 1 hour ago.
Below things worked for me, if you didn't set up these before.

change this below line from true to false in your spec_helper.rb

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```

Next add this file in spec/support/database_cleaner.rb

```
    RSpec.configure do |config|
       config.use_transactional_fixtures = true            #make it false

      config.before(:suite) do
       DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
     end

     config.before(:each) do
      DatabaseCleaner.start
   end

   config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
   end
end
```

You've to clean your database each time you run the test. If you didn't add this file before please make sure add the database_cleaner gem in your gemfile.

```
gem 'database_cleaner'
```